# Convert jQuery timer and redirect to work with minutes and seconds, rather than just seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have found this lightweight and excellent timer and redirect script based on jQuery, created by the '[jQuery by Example](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2013/06/jquery-redirect-page-after-few-seconds.html)' site.  The script redirects the user after a set number of seconds:

HTML:

```
<h1>You will be redirect to actual page after <span id="spnSeconds">10000</span> seconds.</h1>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.setInterval(function () {
        var iTimeRemaining = $("#spnSeconds").html();
        iTimeRemaining = eval(iTimeRemaining);
        if (iTimeRemaining == 0) {
            location.href = "http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/";
        } else {
            $("#spnSeconds").html(iTimeRemaining - 1);
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/2WmJb/

I am trying to modify it to work with minutes and seconds - would anyone know how to do this?  I've tried simply modifying the HTML to 25:00 but this doesn't seem to be working (thought it wouldn't the that simple!).

Many thanks in advance for your help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best to use a data attribute for the time and display whatever you want as the text:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2WmJb/67/

You can access the data attribute with either `.data('time')` or `.attr('data-time')`

```
<h1>You will be redirect to actual page after <span id="spnSeconds" data-time="1500000">25 minutes</span></h1>

$(document).ready(function () {
    window.setInterval(function () {
        var iTimeRemaining = $("#spnSeconds").data('time');
        iTimeRemaining = ~~iTimeRemaining;
        if (iTimeRemaining == 0) {
            location.href = "http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/";
        } else {
            var mins = ~~(iTimeRemaining / 60000);
            $("#spnSeconds").html(mins + " minutes " + ~~(iTimeRemaining / 1000 % 60) + " seconds");
            $("#spnSeconds").data('time', iTimeRemaining - 1000);
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

Also `Eval` is `Evil` in most cases. Do a simple `~~` to coerce the value to an integer value, or use `parseInt`.

### Changes Based on comment - add a pad function for leading zeroes

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2WmJb/69/

```
function pad(num, size) {
    var s = "000000000" + num;
    return s.substr(s.length-size);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    window.setInterval(function () {
        var iTimeRemaining = $("#spnSeconds").data('time');
        iTimeRemaining = ~~iTimeRemaining;
        if (iTimeRemaining == 0) {
            location.href = "http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/";
        } else {
            var mins = ~~(iTimeRemaining / 60000);
            $("#spnSeconds").html(mins + ":" + pad(~~(iTimeRemaining / 1000 % 60),2));
            $("#spnSeconds").data('time', iTimeRemaining - 1000);
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

### One final cleanup: http://jsfiddle.net/2WmJb/70/

Although not really significant when using jQuery `id` selectors (as they are very fast compared to say class selectors), you should reuse variables instead of repeatedly calling jQuery selectors. This example uses `$span` instead of `$("#spnSeconds")`. The $ prefix is a typical prefix for your variables that are jQuery objects (and more readable):

```
var $span = $("#spnSeconds");
var iTimeRemaining = $span.data('time');
iTimeRemaining = ~~iTimeRemaining;
if (iTimeRemaining == 0) {
    location.href = "http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/";
} else {
    $span.html(~~(iTimeRemaining / 60000) + ":" + pad(~~(iTimeRemaining / 1000 % 60),2));
    $span.data('time', iTimeRemaining - 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  This looks really great - my desired output is 25:00 though, rather than '25 minutes and 0 seconds'.  I've deleted the minutes and seconds html code. but how could I add a leading zero to the output when it's less than 10 seconds?  Also, how do I calculate the data-time attribute if wanted to set this dynamically (e.g. for 25:10) ?  Thanks again for your help - really impressed!

Comment: @user2761030: Update as requested... The data-attribute value is simply time in milliseconds so `minutes * 60000 + seconds * 1000`

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Amazing!  Thanks so much for modifying and explaining the milliseconds rule - can now incorporate this into our code!